# How do I know if I have DotNet Core 1.1?

Tags: .net

I've downloaded the SDK from https://dot.net, where I change the UI to "Current" and click on "x64", and it downloads dotnet-dev-win-x64.1.0.0-preview2-1-003177.exe, which I then executed.

Then at command prompt "dotnet --version" reports: 1.0.0-preview2-1-003177

Shouldn't this be 1.1.0 ?

When I download the LTS version 1.0.1, the download is DotNetCore.1.0.1-SDK.1.0.0.Preview2-003133-x64.exe

So it has 1.0.1 in the name, shouldn't the 1.1 version have 1.1 in the name?

Answer (score 1):

> Shouldn't this be 1.1.0 ?

No. `dotnet --version` prints the version of the *CLI*, not the runtime you have installed. You can actually have multiple runtimes installed, but there is no command that actually lists the latest runtime you have installed.

This is all outlined in a GitHub issue here: https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/3773

You can check the filesystem, the location varies by OS. On OS X you can do this: `ls /usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App`

> shouldn't the 1.1 version have 1.1 in the name

That's just the download name. Unfortunately the SDKs with the 1.1 runtime don't actually include 1.1 in the name.